# How to update Jira issue resolution by using Jira Rest java client

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I'm using Jira Rest java client for creating/updating issues and need to update issue's resolution when closing it. I have tried the following code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Issue issue = restClient.getIssueClient().getIssue("CER-3").get();
        Iterator<Transition> transitions =
                restClient.getIssueClient().getTransitions(issue).get().iterator();
        int transitionId = 0;
        while (transitions.hasNext()) {
            Transition transition = transitions.next();
            if (transition.getName().contains("Closed")
                    || transition.getName().contains("Done")) {
                transitionId = transition.getId();
            }
        }
        final Collection<FieldInput> fieldInputs;
        fieldInputs =
                Arrays.asList(new FieldInput("resolution", ComplexIssueInputFieldValue.with(
                        "name", "Won't Fix")));
        TransitionInput tInput =
                new TransitionInput(transitionId, fieldInputs, Comment.valueOf("My comment"));

        restClient.getIssueClient().transition(issue, tInput).claim();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After running the above code the following exception is received:

```
RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(400), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=400, errors={Resolution=Field 'Resolution' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.}, errorMessages=[]}]}
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.DelegatingPromise.claim(DelegatingPromise.java:47)
at com.instigatemobile.cerebro.clients.JiraRestClientModule.main(JiraRestClientModule.java:157)
Caused by: RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(400), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=400, errors={Resolution=Field 'Resolution' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.}, errorMessages=[]}]}
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$2.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:166)
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$2.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:160)
at com.atlassian.httpclient.api.ResponsePromiseMapFunction.apply(ResponsePromiseMapFunction.java:48)
at com.atlassian.httpclient.api.ResponsePromiseMapFunction.apply(ResponsePromiseMapFunction.java:12)
at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$3.apply(Promises.java:285)
at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$2.onSuccess(Promises.java:162)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$7.run(Futures.java:1072)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:253)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList$RunnableExecutorPair.execute(ExecutionList.java:161)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:146)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.done(AbstractFuture.java:235)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:172)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$3.apply(Promises.java:285)
at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$2.onSuccess(Promises.java:162)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$7.run(Futures.java:1072)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:253)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList$RunnableExecutorPair.execute(ExecutionList.java:161)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:146)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.done(AbstractFuture.java:235)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:172)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$1$1.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:46)
at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable$1.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:197)
at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.runInContext(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:90)
at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:192)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Java error hints at field Resolution not being part of the target screen. This happens if your "Edit Issue" screen in Jira doesn't contain the field called "Resolution". Opening the target issue directly in Jira and trying to add the Resolution field, you would see the following pop-up messsage:

[image]

You then need to log into Jira with admin privileges, and edit the "Edit issue" screen to add that field.